# What kind of art is this one?

Tags: illustration, portrait

I need to do the avatars of my team work. And i like this one but i really don't know what kind of arte is this.. I hope you can help me. Thanks..
[image]

Comment: I believe people call this an illustration

Comment: Why did you tag this cs6?

Comment: I know it's illustration. But what I don't know if have some technique.

Comment: It's a line drawing. There's no particular technique to it. Maybe research comic illustration or the like.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple vector avatar. A Google search of this will yield many results as it is usually the first step for people jumping into an illustration program before they move on to specific stylized pieces.

There are many online step by step guides to achieve the result shown in your question. Including [this one](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-vector-avatar-from-a-stock-image--vector-6109) which should set you up quite nicely.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok than's for you'r help Jenna.